# Applying a gradient map from image to another image with transparency in Python (PIL, numpy, etc)

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, python-imaging-library, colormap

I've been struggling with trying to apply a gradient map which is sourced from an image file to a grayscale image which includes alpha/transparency. The following includes the source image and the gradient map image. I first attempted this with numpy and was unsuccessful. The purpose of this is to be able to programmatically color image layers using gradient maps. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

[Sample Source Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQZzg.png)

[Sample Colormap / Gradient to Apply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIiIT.png)

[Sample Intended Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJgzN.png)

Comment: @nathancy I did see this post but it doesn't help with this question. Specifically, the method to use a gradient image as the input cmap.

Comment: Hmm okay question is reopened, hopefully someone has a solution

Comment: It's unclear exactly what mapping you want to apply.  Your first image is almost but not quite grayscale - it has 522 colors rather than the 256 maximum possible with grayscale.  And the second is the same width but only a single pixel high.  Do you want to fill the transparent background with the gradient expanded to be the same height?

Comment: @MarkRansom gradient maps in image processing software allow us to assign the colors of a gradient to the highlights, midtones, and shadows of an image. I've added a new image called "Sample Intended Result" that shows what that would look like. The question from this post is an attempt to apply a gradient map programmatically in Python.

Comment: OK that's kind of what I thought you meant, but it still leaves questions.  Should the almost grayscale input be converted to pure grayscale?  How should those 256 gray values map to the 2000 provided in your gradient image?

Comment: @MarkRansom thank you for the continued response on this thread! I guess we're now getting to the part that I don't completely understand but it sounds like going to true grayscale and matching the image gradient pixel count (i.e. 265 wide by 1 tall) would allow me to color map pixel by pixel to replace the grayscale image with a "gradient" or 256 pixels to replace 256 gray tones. If that is correct, do you have an example of how I would do that in Python code?

Comment: I'll see what I can put together for you when I have a little more time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from PIL import Image

gray, alpha = Image.open(source_fn).convert('LA').split()
gradient = Image.open(gradient_fn).convert('RGB').resize((256, 1))
lut = []
for band in gradient.split():
    lut += list(band.getdata())

out = gray.point(lut, 'RGB')
out.putalpha(alpha)
out.save(out_fn, 'PNG')
```

Here's the result.  It doesn't quite match the example you provided as the intended result, but I think that's just a misunderstanding of how the range of inputs were supposed to map to the gradient.  I'm sure you could fix that yourself.

[image]